# PHP - why should I use pathinfo when I can get it through $_File array

Tags: php

why should I use this code to get the name of the file?

```
$filename = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME)
```

If I could also get the name through this code:

```
$filename = $_File['file']['name']
```

Thank you very much! I'm a beginner in PHP, so sorry if the question is too dumb :D

Comment: `pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME)` strips the extension from the full filename, if that is what is required that would be the reason for using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `$_File['file']['name']` comes from the user end, and although ordinarily it is just the file name, an ill-intentioned user can actually set it to whatever he wants (example: full path name to overwrite files in the server) and you have to filter it just like every other user input to prevent an attack vector in your system.

Same is true for everything in `$_FILE`, don't trust the informed MIME `type`, don't save files without checking if the extension is safe (saving a `.php` file will be a disaster) etc.

For example, I've seen a system that would trust files of `type` equal to `image/jpeg` and other image types, and then saves it without checking the actual file extension. A forged request can inject a `.php` shell script to this website's upload folder and be used to take control.

Comment: thank you very much!! I will keep in mind that I should never trust data that I get from users. I will learn more about security in programming/php! Thank you very much!!